# Usage of this keyword in constructor chaining?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, documentation, msdn

I am reading msdn documentation for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) keyword. They gave three usages for `this` keyword as follows

1. To qualify members hidden by similar names
2. To pass an object as a parameter to other methods
3. To declare indexers

and there is no word about the usage of `this` during [constructor chaining](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271582/Constructor-Chaining-in-Csharp).

My question are :

1. Why they missed out constructor chaining ?
2. Is in some way that constructor chaining is an application of the above three usages that I am not aware of ?

Comment: They must have either overlooked it, or simply decided not to discuss it there.  The use of `this` with constructors is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked says (emphasis mine):

> The following are **common** uses of `this`:

The article doesn't say that `this` doesn't have other uses. In fact, it also explicitly says that it doesn't discuss another use of `this`:

> This article discusses the use of `this` with class instances. For more information about its use in extension methods, see Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide).

If you think that using `this` in constructor chaining should be discussed in that article, consider [filing a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).